# For every cardinal $\kappa$, $\kappa^+$ is regular

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

Again I'm struggling with a proof from [this](http://www.math.unt.edu/%7Emoliver/fa04s/JacksonNotes/card.pdf) introduction to cardinals.

> **Lemma 2.6.** For every cardinal $\kappa$, $\kappa^+$ is regular.
>
> Proof. If not, then there would be a cofinal map $f:\lambda\to\kappa$, where $\lambda\leq \kappa$. This would write $\kappa^+$ as a $\kappa$ union of sets, each of which size $\leq \kappa$. This contradicts theorem 1.8.

I think it should be $f:\lambda\to\kappa^+$, right?

But my main question is how the "this would write" conclusion works. How do we get from a cofinal map to a $\kappa$ union? I've read the entire paper and I still don't get it.

Also, on a side note, is this theorem equivalent to the statement that for any successor ordinal $\alpha$, we have $\text{cf}(\omega_\alpha)=\omega_\alpha$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can probably find the proof that every [successor cardinal is regular](https://www.google.com/search?q=successor+cardinal+is+regular) in many places,
for example, here: [A Successor Cardinal is Regular](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1671071/a-successor-cardinal-is-regular). The discussion of the use of Axiom of Choice in the proof of this result can be found here: [The regularity of successor cardinal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/693535/the-regularity-of-successor-cardinal).

I will only write about the part in this particular proof which you singled out as unclear to you.

---

Suppose that $f \colon \lambda \to \kappa^+$ is cofinal. This means that $\{f(\alpha); \alpha<\lambda\}$ is a cofinal set in $\kappa^+$, i.e.,
$$\sup_{\alpha<\lambda} f(\alpha) = \kappa^+.\tag{1}$$
This is just a different way of writing 
$$\bigcup_{\alpha<\lambda} f(\alpha) = \kappa^+.\tag{2}$$

Notice that we have used $|\lambda|$-many sets and $|\lambda|\le\kappa$.

And we also have $f(\alpha)<\kappa^+$. Since $\kappa^+$ is the smallest ordinal with cardinality $\kappa^+$, cardinality of each $f(\alpha)$ is at most $\kappa$.

So $\kappa^+$ is written $(2)$ as union of at most $\kappa$ sets, each of them having cardinality at most $\kappa$.

Comment: Perfect! I really failed to see $(1)$. :S